# Realizar Insert durante determinada quantidade definida (PHP)

Tags: php, sql-insert

Olá,

Pessoal, quero que uma ação seja realizada durante uma determinada quantidade de vezes definida através de um formulário.
Por exemplo:

O usuário escolhe 5,
então o código isere 5 registros no banco de dados.
Sendo que a cada registro, deve ser incremental, por exemplo, se escolheu 5,
então irá gravar no campo em cada um dos registros, sequencialmente, 1,2,3,4,5.

Imaginei iniciar assim:

```
$valor_escolhido = "5";

foreach($valor_escolhido as $vlr_esc){
    $insert="INSERT INTO TABELA (campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES ('$campo1','$campo2', '$valor_escolhido') ";
}
```

Como ficaria isso...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você irá inserir registros de uma vez, de forma sequencial, você pode fazer assim:

```
$valor = array(); // aqui criamos o array com os valore escolhidos
for($x = 1; $x <= $valor_escolhido; $x++){
    $valor[] = $x ; // aqui inserimos os valores
}

$insert="INSERT INTO TABELA (campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES "; // inicia a string fora do `foreach` 
// abaixo, no foreach você irá concatenar os valores
foreach($valor as $vlr_esc){
   $insert.= "('$campo1','$campo2', '$vlr_esc'),"; // repare que tem uma virgula no final
}
$insert = substr($insert, 0, -1); // aqui você apaga a ultima vírgula
```

Assim é mais fácil:

```
$insert="INSERT INTO TABELA (campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES "; // inicia a string fora do `foreach` 

// abaixo, no for você irá concatenar os valores
$valor_escolhido = 5;
for($x = 1; $x <= $valor_escolhido; $x++){
    $insert.= "('$campo1','$campo2', '$x'),"; // repare que tem uma virgula no final
}
$insert = substr($insert, 0, -1); // aqui você apaga a ultima vírgula
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui assim tbm:

```
$nome="Eu";
$quantidade_escolhida="6";
$a="1";

while($a <= $quantidade_escolhida){

    $insert = "INSERT INTO tabela(id,nome) VALUES ('$a','$nome')";
    $rs_insert = mysql_query($insert);  

    $a++;
}//endwhile;
```

Comment: Assim também é dá Neo. O problema é que dessa forma o servidor pode gerar um erro `to many connections`. Pois o servidor pode ficar sobrecarregado se houver mais quantidades de conexao que o servidor está configurado. Cuidado. =)

Comment: Por isso aconselho você colocar a string de insert fora do while e ir concatenando.